# How can I externalize React v17.0.2 in a Vite-powered project when "react/jsx-runtime" cannot be found?

Tags: reactjs

everyone.  I am trying to externalize **React v17.0.2** in a project because it will work with `single-spa`.  I have externalized `react`, `react-dom` and `react-router-dom`, and I have used the JSDelivr network to provide the libraries through an `importmap` script.

This is my `vite.config.mjs` file:

```js
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react(), devEnvPlugin(), vitePluginSingleSpa({
        type: 'root',
        imo: '3.1.0',
        importMaps: {
            dev: ['src/importMap.Dev.json', 'src/importMap.shared.json'],
            build: ['src/importMap.json', 'src/importMap.shared.json']
        }
    })],
    build: {
        sourcemap: true,
        target: 'es2022',
        rollupOptions: {
            external: [fastrEnvModuleId, "react", "react-dom", "react-router-dom"]
        }
    },
    esbuild: {
        supported: {
            'top-level-await': true
        }
    },
    server: {
        host: true,
        port: 4100,
        proxy: getProxyConfig()
    },
    preview: {
        port: 4100
    }
});
```

Nevermind the proxy and other settings.  Pretty much, I use rollup options to externalize and then I use the following importmap to re-map the externalized bare module identifiers:

```json
{
    "imports": {
        "react": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@esm-bundle/react@17.0.2-fix.1/+esm",
        "react-dom": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@17.0.2/+esm",
        "react-router-dom": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-router-dom@5.3.4/+esm"
    }
}
```

Building with Vite works and the output folder `dist` is generated, at which point I run the preview server.

Now, before I continue, I should tell you that this project uses `@azure/msal-react`.  Without externalized libraries, this project works just fine.  Ok.  Let's continue.

Opening the homepage for the project (http://localhost:4100) to test reveals a nasty error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at ye (react.development.js:1476:13)
    at o.useEffect (react.development.js:1519:20)
    at D1 (MsalProvider.js:76:5)
    at Lu (react-dom.production.min.js:157:137)
    at hs (react-dom.production.min.js:267:460)
    at ns (react-dom.production.min.js:250:347)
    at Ji (react-dom.production.min.js:250:278)
    at Zi (react-dom.production.min.js:250:138)
    at Qi (react-dom.production.min.js:243:163)
    at Ui (react-dom.production.min.js:237:175)
```

As you can see, the stack trace points to `@azure/msal-react`'s `MsalProvider` component.  Because externalizing is the only thing that changes between "works" and "doesn't work", I bet the problem is that I somehow have multiple react-dom's somewhere.  That's what my instinct tells me.

So I do the needful:  `npm ls react` shows that all react dependencies have been deduped; `npm ls react-dom` tells me the same thing.

At this point I just say:  "Let's delete react and react-dom from node_modules, and if it is being used by Vite's build process, I'll know".  Sure enough, I did this and an error appears:  It tells me that `react/jsx-runtime` could not be resolved.  I was happy because I thought this would be a matter of externalizing this bare identifier and then provide the shared copy through the importmap.

This is where I get stuck:  React is not really available in ESM, and as far as I know, only the JSDelivr network has an ESM URL for it, which is the one I show in the importmap.  Now what's the URL for `react/jsx-runtime`?  Doing `"react/": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@esm-bundle/react@17.0.2-fix.1/+esm/"` as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type/importmap#mapping_path_prefixes) doesn't work.

There is a package called `react-jsx-runtime`, but using its URL in the importmap solves nothing, as the error about 2 Reacts still come up.

So at this point I'm at a loss.  Anyone out there that can help out?

### EDIT

I do notice that the error's stack trace, up to `MsalProvider`, shows "react-dom.production.min.js", and after it shows "react.development.js".  I don't know enough React to realize if this is a concern or not.